# How to make multiple inheritance in Kotlin with data class and interface?

Tags: kotlin, data-class

So i have very specific case. I have super class tile

```
open class Tile(@Transient open val type: String, @Transient open val id: String)
```

I have post tile that is currently Interface

```
interface PostTile {
    val id: String
    val author: Author
    val createdDate: String
    var text: PostText?
    val topComment: Comment?
    val seeAllComments: DeeplinkAction?
    val tags: List<Tag>?
}
```

And then all of my different type posts extends Tile and PostTile for example

```
data class MediaTile(
    override val id: String,
    override val type: String,
    override val author: Author,
    override val createdDate: String,
    override var text: PostText?,
    override val topComment: Comment?,
    override val seeAllComments: DeeplinkAction?,
    override val tags: List<Tag>?,
    val images: List<TileImage>?,
    val reactions: PostReactions,
) : PostTile, Tile(type, id)
```

Here is ViewModel:

```
class PostTileViewModel
@AssistedInject
constructor(
    @Assisted private val tile: PostTile,
) : ViewModel() {
    private var originalText = tile.text?.originalText
    private var text = tile.text?.text

    private var _postTileState = MutableStateFlow(tile)
    val tileState = _postTileState.asStateFlow()

    fun translateText() {
        val newText = if (_postTileState.value.text?.isTranslated == true)
            originalText
        else text
        val postText = PostText(
            text = newText,
            isTranslated = !_postTileState.value.text?.isTranslated!!,
            originalText = tile.text?.originalText
        )
        _postTileState.value.text = postText
    }

    @AssistedFactory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(
            @Assisted tile: PostTile,
        ): PostTileViewModel
    }

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    companion object {
        fun provideFactory(
            assistedFactory: Factory,
            tile: PostTile
        ): ViewModelProvider.Factory = object : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
            override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
                return assistedFactory.create(tile) as T
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is PostTileView that is connected to view model

```
@Composable
fun PostTileView(
    tile: PostTile,
    content: @Composable (
        tile: PostTile,
    ) -> Unit
) {
    val postTileViewModel = postTileViewModel(
        tile,
        id = tile.id
    )
    val postTile = postTileViewModel.tileState.collectAsState().value
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Style.colors.content)
            .padding(bottom = 10.dp)
    ) {
        PostTileHeaderView(postTile.author, createdDate = postTile.createdDate)
        content(postTile)
        if(postTile.text?.originalText != null) {
            Button(onClick = {
                postTileViewModel.translateText()
            }) {
                val buttonTitle = if(postTile.text!!.isTranslated == true)
                    "Show original" else "Translate"
                Text(text = buttonTitle)
            }
        }
        PostTags(tags = postTile.tags)
    }
}
```

And here is MediaTileView

```
@Composable
fun MediaTileView(tile: MediaTile) {
    PostTileView(tile = tile) {
        if(it.text?.text != null){
            ExpandableTextView(
                text = it.text?.text!!,
                style = Style.typography.bodyBold,
                color = Style.colors.textStandard,
                minimizedMaxLines = if (tile.images != null) 2 else 10,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 15.dp, end = 10.dp)
            )
        }
        if (tile.images != null) {
            TileImageView(
                images = tile.images, modifier =
                Modifier
                    .height(300.dp)
                    .padding(start = 15.dp, end = 15.dp, top = 20.dp)
                    .clip(
                        RoundedCornerShape(10.dp)
                    )
            )
        }
    }
}
```

I need to make PostTile as data class because I used it in viewmodel. What is best way to achieve it?

Comment: It is not possible to extend a data class and frankly, it wouldn't make too much sense. Data classes do not provide any kind of functionality from the type system perspective, so we never really are forced to use them. They provide utility-like functionality by auto-generating some code and this functionality pretty much conflicts with inheritance. `MediaTile` is not a valid `PostTile` data class as e.g. its `equals` does not work properly for equality checks between `PostTile` objects.

Comment: I know that but how to make this to work. Than probably my complete setup is wrong :(

Comment: I don't understand why do you think `PostTile` has to be a data class. There is no such requirement in viewmodel. Generally speaking, It is always more flexible and better to use interfaces wherever possible. Your `Tile` also makes things harder, because it is a class. It is hard to give you specific answers, because we don't know what is `Tile`, `PostTile` and `MediaTile`, how they relate to each other, etc.

Comment: I have problem in ViewModel to update mutable state flow which initial values is PostTile. Thats why i thought it would be nicer to deal with data classes.

Comment: `MediaTile` *is* a `PostTile` though. Do you actually need to make concrete `PostTile` instances, or is it more of an abstract thing and all the objects you actually *use* will be `MediaTile`s and maybe others like `ImageTile` or whatever? Do you need to construct a `PostTile` with `PostTile(...)`, basically. If not, you don't need to make it a concrete class!

Comment: PostTile has common properties for all other tiles. I have MediaTile, QuestionTile and so on. All this setup works but now I have hard time in ViewModel where i have MustableStateFlow with initial value of PostTile to update it. It would be much easier with Data class

Comment: @broot i have updated question so you can see how they relate to each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new data class called `PostTileState` which extends `PostTile` and use that class in your viewModel:

```
data class PostTileState(
    override val id: String,
    override val author: Author,
    override val createdDate: String,
    override var text: PostText?,
    override val topComment: Comment?,
    override val seeAllComments: DeeplinkAction?,
    override val tags: List<Tag>?
): PostTile
```

Comment: In order to make it work I need MediaTile also change to implement PostTileState as it will not otherwise and it is not possible to extend from data class...

Comment: why there is not need to make MediaTile implement PostTileState

Comment: In UI i have composable PostTileView that shares common UI things for every post .Here is gist https://gist.github.com/Jalson1982/5fd6c5c98e3a80788e804d52a587a412